# Unable to create project from archetype using playn eclipse and maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, playn

This is pretty frustrating.  I followed the GettingStarted instructions on the PlayN page and everything works fine from the command line but I keep getting errors when trying to create a skeleton PlayN maven project in eclipse.  I'm running this on a Mac OS X and eclipse 4.2.0 classic.

> Unable to create project from archetype [com.googlecode.playn:playn-archetype:1.3.1]

Under details it says: 
The defined artifact is not an archetype

Comment: Have you installed m2e plugin? Based on the eclipse documentation it is not part of the classic download?

Comment: Yes, I installed the m2e plugin and the m2e android plugin into eclipse too.

Comment: I also have the same problem in the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266520/error-importing-maven-android-android-project-to-eclipse-with-adt-20 I don't know if it's related?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a working solution, albeit less pretty. Essentially, if you create a new project with Maven (not Eclipse), then import it in, you won't see this error. See [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357237/unable-to-create-skeleton-playn-project-in-eclipse/11366975#11366975) answers for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way better solution that actually works. I dumped eclipse and followed this tutorial for netbeans http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/05/24/Using-Netbeans-712-with-PlayN-13.aspx