# Unable to create skeleton PlayN project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, playn

I'm getting to the point where I've almost given up trying to use PlayN. I've tried PlayN's Getting Started guide [here](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted), as well as GamesFromScratch's updated guide [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/07/PlayN-install-guide_The-new-way.aspx), with no luck. Every time I try and create a New->Other->"Maven Project" with the code.googlecode.playn 1.3.1 archetype, I get this error message:

> 'Creating playn-archetype' has encountered a problem
>
> Unable to create project from archetype [com.googlecode.playn:playn-archetype:1.3.1]
>   The defined artifact is not an archetype

I wonder if I'm doing anything wrong? I've read that Eclipse ships with Maven version 3.0.2 (I'm using Eclipse Juno), so I installed Maven 3.0.4, though I don't know how to upgrade Eclipse's version (or if it makes any difference).

Many Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse Juno comes embedded with Maven 3.0.4, so that was not the problem.

Here is a solution I came up with:

1. Download apache-maven-3.0.x from [Apache](http://maven.apache.org/)
2. (On Windows) Add the location of the bin folder in apache-maven-3.0.x to your PATH environment variable (Click on edit, add a semicolon and the path to the bin folder to the end)
3. Generate a new project with Maven (not Eclipse):

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.playn -DarchetypeArtifactId=playn-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.1
>
> (In Eclipse) File->Import->Existing Maven Project; browse to where you generated the project (probably your user folder) and import.
>
> To run the project, run as "Maven test" on gameName, edit gameName-core
>
> Cheers!

Comment: This workaround seems to be working. But I wonder how can we really solve this issue to allow people creating projects from eclipse.

Comment: This workaround has worked for me on OSX with Eclipse Juno. I only needed to follow steps 1 and 2, change Eclipse version of Maven to the 'external' version downloaded from Apache. **Then** I resolved all the errors (for Java projects) with Quick Fix

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Maven runtime to the Window/Preferences/Maven/Installations. After this -in case you have previous Maven Run Configurations- you might have to update those too, to use this new Maven.