# Creating playN project

Tags: eclipse, playn

I'm getting some problem in understanding playN project, can someone explain how to create a playN project or point me to a link that has enough documentation. I've used the playN samples. its really confusing. Does someone has a link that has proper documentation for playN??

Answer (score 2):

I beleive it is possible to create new playn projects based on this guide: http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted#Creating_a_new_project

Also, this is a related question: [Unable to create skeleton PlayN project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357237/unable-to-create-skeleton-playn-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: The "Getting Started" instructions are (as of July 29 2012) out of date, however the "Unable to create skeleton PlayN project in Eclipse" workaround does work (on OSX with Eclipse Juno)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Since then, they released 1.4, but they still suggests 1.3.1 (maybe the archetype is not yet in Maven Central). There might be other inconsistencies, I have not checked in depth. I know there were problems recently with the m2e-android plugin, but the recent release fixed it. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Here a good guide:

http://www.thescreencast.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-playn-cross.html

http://www.thescreencast.com/2012/01/part-i-has-shown-how-to-install-and-use.html

**And a better one which i used:**

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/?tag=/PlayN

**Updated: installation Guide**
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/06/GFS-PlayN-Installer%E2%80%93Super-detailed-installation-instructions.aspx
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/10/13/Getting-started-with-PlayN.aspx

**And here the PlayN automated installer!**
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/downloads/PlayN/GFSPlaynInstaller.zip

Now just Extract the zip file to any folder ( make sure you extract though, do not run from the zip ) and run Install.cmd
Now it is simply a matter of answering a couple Yes/No questions, and (optionally) point the installer at your JDK folder and telling it where you want PlayN to be installed.  Except the gotcha… read about that below before running the install!
[Guide](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/06/GFS-PlayN-Installer%E2%80%93Super-detailed-installation-instructions.aspx)

Comment: Also ask your question or the error code you receive so we can help you more.

Comment: Neither of those guides provide sufficient instructions to successfully install and use PlayN. In fact it just shows the use of PlayN in a working environment, but nothing about the steps to get it working

Comment: @avasopht how much how you tried to do this? it's not that complicate! which step stop you? what is the error you get?

Comment: @Noor I have add some new links. Hope to Help.